# Ffmpeg Android - First image is skipped while making a slideshow

Tags: android, kotlin, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

**Issue : I have 7 images in a list (with different size, resolution and format). I am adding an mp3 audio file and fade effect while making a slideshow with them, as i am trying to do it by following command**

```
val inputCommandinitial = arrayOf("-y", "-framerate", "1/5")
val arrTop = ArrayList<String>()

 //Add all paths
    for (i in images!!.indices) {
        arrTop.add("-loop")
        arrTop.add("1")
        arrTop.add("-t")
        arrTop.add("5")            
        arrTop.add("-i")
        arrTop.add(images!![i].path)
    }

    //Apply filter graph
    arrTop.add("-i")
    arrTop.add(audio!!.path)
    arrTop.add("-filter_complex")

    val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()

    for (i in images!!.indices) {
        stringBuilder.append("[$i:v]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v$i];")
    }

    for (i in images!!.indices) {
        stringBuilder.append("[v$i]")
    }

    //Concat command
    stringBuilder.append("concat=n=${images!!.size}:v=1:a=0,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v]")

    val endcommand = arrayOf("-map", "[v]", "-map", "${images!!.size}:a", "-c:a", "copy", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-shortest", outputLocation.path)
    val finalCommand = (inputCommandinitial + arrTop + stringBuilder.toString() + endcommand)
```

**But, it skips the first image and shows the rest 6 images and video output duration is 30 seconds, i've been trying since 3 days now**

**Requirement:
making a slideshow with different format, size, resolution etc, i.e. picked by user from gallery and show in slideshow adding an audio behind, with fade effect**

Here is the complete log:

```
I/mobile-ffmpeg: Loading mobile-ffmpeg.
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Loaded mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl-x86-4.4-lts-20200803.
 D/mobile-ffmpeg: Callback thread started.
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   configuration: --cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=i686 --cpu=i686 --cc=i686-linux-android16-clang --cxx=i686-linux-android16-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --disable-neon --disable-asm --disable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-libxvid --enable-gpl --enable-libx265 --enable-gpl --enable-libvidstab --enable-gpl --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #0, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image1.png':
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: png, rgb24(pc), 800x500 [SAR 11811:11811 DAR 8:5]
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: ,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 0.20 tbr,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 0.20 tbn,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 0.20 tbc
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [png_pipe @ 0xe1a8ec00] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #1, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image2.png':
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #1:0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 3779:3779 DAR 16:9]
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: ,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbr,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbn,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbc
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #2, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/one.png':
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #2:0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: png, rgba(pc), 720x1280
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: ,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 fps,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbr,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbn,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbc
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #3, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/two.png':
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 00:00:00.04
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , start:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 0.000000
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 7955 kb/s
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #3:0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 564x1002 [SAR 72:72 DAR 94:167]
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: ,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 fps,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbr,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbn,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbc
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [png_pipe @ 0xe1a90a00] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #4, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image3.png':
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #4:0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1820x1024
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: ,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbr,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbn,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbc
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #5, png_pipe, from '/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image4.png':
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #5:0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1920x800 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 12:5]
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: ,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 fps,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbr,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbn,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbc
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #6, image2, from '/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image5.png':
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 00:00:00.04
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , start:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 0.000000
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 159573 kb/s
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #6:0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1600x900
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: ,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 fps,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbr,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbn,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbc
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [mp3 @ 0xe1a92800] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Input #7, mp3, from '/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/shortmusic.mp3':
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Metadata:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     track           :
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     artist          :
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: longzijun
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     title           :
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Memoryne Music Box Version
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     album_artist    :
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: longzijun
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     genre           :
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Soundtrack
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     date            :
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 2012
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Duration:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 00:00:57.70
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , start:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 0.000000
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: , bitrate:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 320 kb/s
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #7:0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Stream mapping:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #0:0 (png) -> scale
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #2:0 (png) -> scale
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #3:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #4:0 (png) -> scale
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #5:0 (png) -> scale
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #6:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   format
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:  -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Stream #7:0 -> #0:1
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:  (copy)
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0xe1a1bec0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0xe1a1bf20] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 2:0 @ 0xe1a1bfe0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 3:0 @ 0xe1a1c0a0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 4:0 @ 0xe1a1c160] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 5:0 @ 0xe1a1c220] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [graph 0 input from stream 6:0 @ 0xe1a1c2e0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [swscaler @ 0xbf684840] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
 W/mobile-ffmpeg: [swscaler @ 0xbf68fec0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] using SAR=1/1
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] using cpu capabilities: none!
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=4 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/video/movie_1615954349867.mp4':
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:   Metadata:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     encoder         :
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Lavf58.48.100
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], q=-1--1
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: ,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 fps,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 12800 tbn,
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 25 tbc
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:  (default)
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Metadata:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:       encoder         :
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Lavc58.96.100 libx264
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Side data:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: cpb:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: vbv_delay: N/A
 I/mobile-ffmpeg:     Stream #0:1
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: : Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=    7 fps=3.8 q=20.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=   9.6kbits/s speed=0.0215x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   15 fps=6.3 q=22.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=   1.1kbits/s speed=0.151x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   24 fps=8.2 q=23.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:00.72 bitrate=2912.9kbits/s speed=0.245x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   33 fps=9.5 q=14.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:01.08 bitrate=3883.7kbits/s speed=0.31x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   44 fps= 11 q=12.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:01.52 bitrate=2759.5kbits/s speed=0.379x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   55 fps= 12 q=12.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:01.96 bitrate=2140.1kbits/s speed=0.432x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   68 fps= 13 q=12.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:02.48 bitrate=2537.0kbits/s speed=0.491x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   77 fps= 14 q=12.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:02.84 bitrate=2215.4kbits/s speed=0.499x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   84 fps= 13 q=12.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:03.12 bitrate=2016.6kbits/s speed=0.499x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=   94 fps= 14 q=12.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:03.52 bitrate=1787.4kbits/s speed=0.52x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  102 fps= 14 q=12.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:03.84 bitrate=1638.5kbits/s speed=0.525x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  116 fps= 15 q=12.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:04.40 bitrate=1429.9kbits/s speed=0.556x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  127 fps= 15 q=12.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:04.84 bitrate=1299.9kbits/s speed=0.574x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  134 fps= 15 q=21.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:05.12 bitrate=1228.9kbits/s speed=0.571x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  140 fps= 15 q=22.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:05.36 bitrate=1565.1kbits/s speed=0.56x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  145 fps= 14 q=23.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:05.56 bitrate=1508.8kbits/s speed=0.55x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  151 fps= 14 q=23.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:05.80 bitrate=1807.9kbits/s speed=0.546x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  164 fps= 15 q=12.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:06.32 bitrate=1991.0kbits/s speed=0.567x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  172 fps= 15 q=12.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:06.64 bitrate=1895.1kbits/s speed=0.569x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  186 fps= 15 q=12.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:07.20 bitrate=1747.7kbits/s speed=0.592x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  207 fps= 16 q=12.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:08.04 bitrate=1565.1kbits/s speed=0.634x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  229 fps= 17 q=12.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:08.92 bitrate=1645.8kbits/s speed=0.677x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  249 fps= 18 q=12.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:09.72 bitrate=1510.3kbits/s speed=0.71x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  270 fps= 19 q=21.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:10.56 bitrate=1588.8kbits/s speed=0.744x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  296 fps= 20 q=12.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:11.60 bitrate=1627.1kbits/s speed=0.789x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  319 fps= 21 q=12.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:12.52 bitrate=1507.6kbits/s speed=0.823x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  337 fps= 21 q=12.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:13.24 bitrate=1425.6kbits/s speed=0.839x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  347 fps= 21 q=12.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:13.64 bitrate=1383.8kbits/s speed=0.835x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  360 fps= 21 q=12.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:14.16 bitrate=1481.1kbits/s speed=0.841x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  382 fps= 22 q=19.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:15.04 bitrate=1394.4kbits/s speed=0.866x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  395 fps= 22 q=22.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:15.56 bitrate=1482.6kbits/s speed=0.869x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  407 fps= 22 q=15.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:16.04 bitrate=1569.0kbits/s speed=0.872x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  421 fps= 22 q=12.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:16.60 bitrate=1516.0kbits/s speed=0.875x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  432 fps= 22 q=12.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:17.04 bitrate=1476.9kbits/s speed=0.875x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  446 fps= 22 q=12.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:17.60 bitrate=1429.9kbits/s speed=0.88x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  458 fps= 22 q=12.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:18.08 bitrate=1507.9kbits/s speed=0.879x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  472 fps= 22 q=12.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:18.64 bitrate=1462.6kbits/s speed=0.884x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  489 fps= 23 q=12.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:19.32 bitrate=1411.1kbits/s speed=0.894x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  509 fps= 23 q=19.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:20.12 bitrate=1355.0kbits/s speed=0.909x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  531 fps= 23 q=15.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:21.00 bitrate=1398.1kbits/s speed=0.928x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  555 fps= 24 q=12.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:21.96 bitrate=1432.5kbits/s speed=0.949x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  577 fps= 24 q=12.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:22.84 bitrate=1377.3kbits/s speed=0.966x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  599 fps= 25 q=12.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:23.72 bitrate=1326.2kbits/s speed=0.981x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  620 fps= 25 q=12.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:24.56 bitrate=1280.8kbits/s speed=0.995x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  630 fps= 25 q=18.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:24.96 bitrate=1260.3kbits/s speed=0.99x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  640 fps= 25 q=21.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:25.36 bitrate=1323.1kbits/s speed=0.985x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  652 fps= 25 q=22.0 size=    4352kB time=00:00:25.84 bitrate=1379.7kbits/s speed=0.984x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  665 fps= 25 q=12.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:26.36 bitrate=1432.1kbits/s speed=0.984x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  678 fps= 25 q=12.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:26.88 bitrate=1404.4kbits/s speed=0.984x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  690 fps= 25 q=12.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:27.36 bitrate=1379.7kbits/s speed=0.983x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  703 fps= 25 q=12.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:27.88 bitrate=1354.0kbits/s speed=0.983x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  716 fps= 25 q=12.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:28.40 bitrate=1329.2kbits/s speed=0.983x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  729 fps= 25 q=12.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:28.92 bitrate=1305.3kbits/s speed=0.983x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  742 fps= 25 q=12.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:29.44 bitrate=1282.2kbits/s speed=0.983x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: frame=  749 fps= 25 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4883kB time=00:00:29.95 bitrate=1335.5kbits/s speed=0.988x
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: video:3696kB audio:1171kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: 0.326516%
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] frame I:3     Avg QP:13.33  size:  2725
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] frame P:746   Avg QP:13.98  size:  5062
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] mb P  I16..4:  7.1%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  8.2%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:84.7%
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 14.5% 19.0% 6.9% inter: 5.1% 5.4% 1.4%
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] i16 v,h,dc,p: 65% 18%  7%  9%
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 71% 19%  6%  4%
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: [libx264 @ 0xe1ad4400] kb/s:1010.47
 I/mobile-ffmpeg: Async command execution completed successfully.
```

and here is command is ffmpeg syntax

```
"-y"
"-framerate"
"1/5"
"-loop"
"1"
"-t"
"5"
"-i"
"/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image1.png"
"-loop"
"1"
"-t"
"5"
"-i"
 "/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image2.png"
 "-loop"
 "1"
 "-t"
 "5"
 "-i"
 "/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/one.png"
 "-loop"
 "1"
 "-t"
 "5"
 "-i"
 "/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/two.png"
 "-loop"
 "1"
 "-t"
 "5"
 "-i"
 "/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image3.png"
 "-loop"
 "1"
 "-t"
 "5"
 "-i"
 "/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image4.png"
 "-loop"
 "1"
 "-t"
 "5"
 "-i"
 "/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/image5.png"
 "-i"
 "/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/shortmusic.mp3"
 "-filter_complex"
 "[0:v]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v0];
[1:v]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v1];
[2:v]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v2];
[3:v]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v3];
[4:v]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v4];
[5:v]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v5];
[6:v]scale=720:1280:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=5:d=1[v6];
[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5][v6]concat=n=7:v=1:a=0,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v]"
 "-map"
 "[v]"
 "-map"
 "7:a"
 "-c:a"
 "copy"
 "-preset"
 "ultrafast"
 "-shortest"
 "/storage/emulated/0/FFMpeg Example/video/movie_1615955101725.mp4"
```

Comment: Is the problem with your script or with ffmpeg or both? The android and kotlin stuff may be just noise and in the way. You should run the ffmpeg command plain, unscripted in a terminal on your computer and get it working before scripting it. You should show us the ffmpeg command that is actually being executed and the **complete** log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: @llogan Hi, it seems like its the problem with the command maybe I am missing something, I attached the log and everything seems to look fine in the log I guess, as i said i am getting output video with only 6 images, not 7, ffmpeg is skipping first image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `-framerate 1/5`. That's too low of a value for your given `-t` and it won't work well with fade (image a fade at 0.2 fps). You're only applying that to the first input, while the rest are using the default `-framerate 25`. Remove it and the image will be visible.

Alternatively, use `-framerate 1` for each image input, and add `fps=25` after each `setsar`. It will be significantly faster.

Comment: yes removing  `-framerate 1/5`  worked, also i want to changed the '-t' from 5 to seconds chosen by user i.e. '-t 10' so it will show 1 picture for 10 seconds?, i mean single picture time to show.

Comment: @M.BilalAsif Yes, but don't forget to also update the fade `st`.